# NaiveBayes Algorithm returns "NaN"

Tags: perl, machine-learning, naivebayes

I am using the Perl
[`Algorithm::NaiveBayes`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::NaiveBayes)
module to classify text

I am adding the length of the text as attribute. I have about 1,000 texts, most of which have different lengths? When I try to predict new text I get a ***NaN*** result. If I limiting the training to 10 the ***NaN*** issue goes away.

Is it better in this case to normalize the length to different brackets? Something like

- text length 0-10 return the same value for the attribute
- text length 11-20 return different value of the attribute

Could someone also help me to understand why I get the ***NaN***? I am using code like this:

```
my $result = $nb->predict( attributes => { bar => 3, blurp => 2 } );

print $result->{CAT1}, "\n";
print $result->{CAT2}, "\n";
```

Comment: Please show the full exact text of the `NaN` error. What do you mean by *"if i limiting my text to let's 10"*? Ten what?

Comment: i fixed my test , i mean if i limiting the training to 10 instead of 100 the NAN goes away, its not eror i get just NAN as value when i  print the $result->{CAT1} or $result->{CAT2} ,where CAT1 and CAT2 are my labels

Comment: Without the text themselves, the full program, and also the exact text of the error, it's impossible to know. Might be some typo somewhere. I really doubt it's got to do with the length of the texts, but it might be the case that texts are converted to vectors and you are training with vectors of different length. Also, the GitHub repo for the module might allow you to post issues, they will probably be more versed in their own code's errors.